# Areas option in solution explore not display in visual studio 2019

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-mvc-areas

Today I updated visual studio 2019 to  **version 16.3 to  16.4** but problem that i am **unable to see or add Areas** in my current project solution explore

how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right-click on the project
2. add Scaffold item and you will see

[image]